# Changing version at Setup Project dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to change version of Setup project in VS dynamically, from generated class? Can i do that?

Comment: Please provide additional information so that we can determine what you need and how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

All VS projects are basically text files, so theoretically you can do what you want, but maybe not from inside VS.

You will want to change the ProductVersion property of the project. In the text file, look for a line containing something like the following:

```
        "ProductVersion" = "8:1.0.1001"
```

The "1.0.1001" part should be whatever your current version is. The 8: seems to be a type identifier; I would guess 8 means a string.

When you update the ProductVersion, you should also update the ProductCode. This is simply a GUID, so you can simply generate and ToString() a new random GUID. DO NOT TOUCH the UpgradeCode if you want the installer to find previous versions of your program and remove them.

This is all perfectly possible to do with a simple .NET program. Integrating it into a VS build is trickier, because the install project is not an MSBuild script like the others, so you don't have access to the kinds of custom build logic tools you have in MSBuild from directly inside the install project. You could set up your primary project's MSBuild script to include a build task to update the install project version when built, possibly. You could also set up a post-build action.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a script file you can use to increment that version number calling it from a PreBuild event of a setup project. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22256/NewSetupVersion-for-MSI-Projects)

Read the issue raised by amthog in the comments though. The fact that the project is not reloaded after this script runs, but prior to the build can cause headaches. I have a post build event that is now failing due to changes made "externally" (by this script) which haven't been reloaded at the time the post build event runs.

If that doesn't concern you, this script seems to work well.